# Very slow rendering of text tables and maps in the print layout in new versions of QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm using QGIS 3.34. In the print layout composer, text tables are very slow. When they have more than 100-200 lines, each movement through the layout takes 2-3 seconds (even if there are no maps there).

I noticed that this problem started around version 3.10. Now in QGIS it has become simply impossible to work with large text tables in the print layout.

[image: text tables in QGIS layout]

In addition, before version 3 of QGIS, rendering of maps in the print layout (refresh) occurred at the click of a button. Now maps are rendered in the print layout constantly, which also slows down the system in the case of complex maps.

In general, the print layout in new versions of QGIS has slowed down noticeably compared to older versions. If the map is simple, then this is not noticeable, but if the map has a lot of layers and there are tables, then it is now almost impossible to work in the print layout.

Does anyone have experience solving similar problems?